# Update from Qt 5.5.1 to Qt 5.6 leads to linking errors

Tags: qbs

I just try to update a project from Qt5.5.1 to Qt5.6 and now it fails during linking.

```
C:/Qt/Qt5.6.0/Tools/mingw492_32/bin/../lib/gcc/i686-w64-mingw32/4.9.2/../../../../i686-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: cannot find -lC:/Qt/Qt5.6.0/5.6/mingw49_32/lib/liblibQt5Core.a
C:/Qt/Qt5.6.0/Tools/mingw492_32/bin/../lib/gcc/i686-w64-mingw32/4.9.2/../../../../i686-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: cannot find -lC:/Qt/Qt5.6.0/5.6/mingw49_32/lib/liblibQt5Sql.a
C:/Qt/Qt5.6.0/Tools/mingw492_32/bin/../lib/gcc/i686-w64-mingw32/4.9.2/../../../../i686-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: cannot find -lC:/Qt/Qt5.6.0/5.6/mingw49_32/lib/liblibQt5Gui.a
C:/Qt/Qt5.6.0/Tools/mingw492_32/bin/../lib/gcc/i686-w64-mingw32/4.9.2/../../../../i686-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: cannot find -lC:/Qt/Qt5.6.0/5.6/mingw49_32/lib/liblibQt5Widgets.a
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

The programm compiled fine with QT5.5.1 using qbs.
Now I added the new QT Version and I get these errors. 
I have no idea, why qbs adding two time the "lib" prefix, nor why qbs is trying to use it at all. This program should use the shared libraries of Qt.

[image: qbs_profile_qt_5_6_0]

Could someone give me a hint, how I can fix this? Or what the cause of the problem might be?

Comment: What version of qbs (or Qt Creator) are you using? Similar issues were reported as QBS-688 and QBS-714 in the Qt bug tracker.

Comment: Sorry for taking so long, we had a long weekend.  I'm using qbs 1.4.5.  It looks pretty much like QBS-714, but that should be fixed since qbs 1.3.5.

Comment: Can you see if you still encounter this issue with qbs 1.5.0? (it was released just two days ago)

Comment: Tried it out with qbs 1.5.0.  Now everything seems to work as expected.  Thanx :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This issue was resolved in qbs 1.5.0.